Struggle with sql counting
I need to calculate the (quarterly sessions conversion rate) = (number of orders) / (number of sessions) for an online store.
Here is the data table:
CREATE TABLE orders_full (
    order_id,
    sessions_id,
    created_time
)

CREATE TABLE sessions_data (
    -- records all the sessions (includes the one customers does not order anything)
    sessions_id,
    created_time.
)

I managed to get quarterly total number of orders by counting function. However, To get the conversion rate,I need to count all the sessions occurs each quarter.
Desired result:
year  quarter  number of orders  number of sessions  rate of conversion
2021     1            ...               ...                ...
2022     2            ...              ...                ...

I tried this code:
select 
    datepart(YEAR, orders_full.created_at)              as 'year',
    datepart(QUARTER,orders_full.created_at)            as 'quarter',
    count(orders_full.order_id)                                     as 'order created at this quarter',
    count(sessions_data.session_id)                                 as 'sessions created at this quarter'
'100*count(orders_full.order_id)/count(sessions_data.sesssion_id) as'conversion rate
from orders_full
right outer join sessions_data on sessions_

full.session_id

group by datepart(YEAR,orders_full.created_at), datepart(QUARTER,orders_full.created_at)
--having datepart(year, sessions_data.created_at) = datepart(year,orders_full.created_at) 
order by datepart(YEAR,orders_full.created_at), datepart(QUARTER,orders_full.created_at) ASC

It always give the conversions rate of 100% with same sessions and orders created each quarter.
is there any way to fix this issue?

Please use a title which relates to the problem to be solved

Pleas also use the code formatting option in the editor

Please also provide a [mre] with sample data and desired results  (using table markdown not images)

You're probably running into the integer devision issue where an int divided by an int always gives an int. You need to convert one of the numbers to a decimal.

Side note, don't use single quotes (') for aliases. Single quotes are for literal strings, not delimit identifying object names. They have some "gotchas" as their behaviour is not consistent depending on where they are referenced. Also some syntaxes with literal string aliases are deprecated. Stick to object and alias names that don't need delimit identifying, and if you must delimit identify them use T-SQL's identifier, brackets ([]), or ANSI-SQL's, double quotes (").

I suggest that you pregroup the orders and the sessions by quarterly date separately and then left join them back together, now you're doing a multiple on multiple join, which will never work. Also as other said, your division is probably wrong, compare: select 1 / 5, 1 / 5.0

Most people find main table LEFT JOIN optional data much easier to get than optional data RIGHT JOIN main table.

I just noticed, your FROM appears to be incomplete. RIGHT OUTER JOIN sessions_data on sessions_ full.session_id; sessions_ what full.session_id? =? !=? Something else entirely?

Side note - Starting with SQL Server 2022, you may find the DATETRUNC() function useful, as in DATETRUNC(quarter, orders_full.created_at).

@DianneMarieMiranda - Why did you add a postgresql tag to a question tagged as sql-server?

You are counting rows in your selected set ; it doesn't matter what column name you put in count() (they will be the same as long as session_id and order_id are not null). If you want to count the unique sessions, you can use:
count(distinct sessions_data.session_id)

If there is a chance that this can be zero (because some session_ids are null for some combinations of year & quarter, for example), then you can use something like this for your division:
100*count(orders_full.order_id)/nullif(count(distinct sessions_data.sesssion_id),0)

This avoids divide by zero errors by forcing the result to null.
Also to consider is 'integer division'; count returns an integer, so an integer divided by another integer, will not have decimals by default. if you want the result of the division to be accurate to some decimals, you can convert some operands to a 'non-integer numeric' data type (carefully considering the order and precedence of operators), like:
  100. 
* count(orders_full.order_id)
/ nullif(count(distinct sessions_data.sesssion_id),0)

The decimal point in 100., converts the result of 100. * count(orders_full.order_id) to have 6 decimals.

Hope this will works for you.
WITH QuarterlyOrders AS (
    SELECT 
        DATEPART(YEAR, created_time) AS year,
        DATEPART(QUARTER, created_time) AS quarter,
        COUNT(order_id) AS number_of_orders
    FROM orders_full
    GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, created_time), DATEPART(QUARTER, created_time)
),

QuarterlySessions AS (
    SELECT 
        DATEPART(YEAR, created_time) AS year,
        DATEPART(QUARTER, created_time) AS quarter,
        COUNT(sessions_id) AS number_of_sessions
    FROM sessions_data
    GROUP BY DATEPART(YEAR, created_time), DATEPART(QUARTER, created_time)
)

SELECT 
    qOrders.year,
    qOrders.quarter,
    qOrders.number_of_orders,
    qSessions.number_of_sessions,
    100.0 * qOrders.number_of_orders / qSessions.number_of_sessions AS conversion_rate
FROM 
    QuarterlyOrders qOrders
    FULL OUTER JOIN QuarterlySessions qSessions
    ON qOrders.year = qSessions.year AND qOrders.quarter = qSessions.quarter
ORDER BY 
    qOrders.year, qOrders.quarter;

